# 'Vehicle' is not valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

VS keeps giving me the error mentioned in the title for every function for a class project (at least, all of the ones in Vehicle.h), and I can't figure it out no matter how hard I try. It doesn't seem to be due to any circular definitions, but maybe the answer is simple. The project is supposed to be based on four files (two header files and two .cpp's); I'll attach them below.

Vehicle.h:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    //Declaring Dealer class
    class Dealer
    {
    public:
        Dealer();
        int getDealerNum();
        void setDealerNum(int dealerNumber);
    private:
        int dealerNumber;
        Dealer *dealer;
    };

//Declaring Vehicle class
class Vehicle
{
public:
    Dealer *dealerType;
    Vehicle(string VIN, string make, string model, int year, double price);
    Vehicle();
    string getVIN();
    string getMake();
    string getModel();
    int getYear();
    double getPrice();
    void setVIN(string VIN);
    void setMake(string make);
    void setModel(string model);
    void setYear(int year);
    void setPrice(double price);
    friend Vehicle;
private:
    string VIN;
    string make;
    string model;
    int year;
    double price;
};
```

Functions.h (only one function included, to save some space):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

//Declaring name for input and output file
ofstream outfile;
ifstream infile;

void displayInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles)
{
    int i = 0;
    char query = 'a';
    int j = vehicles.size();
    //Simple loop to display the inventory, with a pause function to wait     for user exit
    while (query != 'x'&&query!='X')
    {
        for (i; i < j; i++)
        {
            cout << "Vehicle #" << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "Vin: " << vehicles[i].getVIN << endl;
            cout << "Make: " << vehicles[i].getMake << endl;
            cout << "Model: " << vehicles[i].getModel << endl;
            cout << "Year: " << vehicles[i].getYear << endl;
            cout << "Price: $" << vehicles[i].getPrice << endl << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "Enter 'x' to return to main menu" << endl;
        cin >> query;
        cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include "Thomas-PA3 Functions.h"
#include "Thomas-PA3 Vehicle.h"
using namespace std;

void displayInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);
void addInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);
void deleteInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);
void updateInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);
void sortInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);
void searchInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);
void writeInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);
void refreshInventory(vector<Vehicle>& vehicles);

int main()
{
    char menu='0';
    vector<Dealer>dealers;
    vector<Vehicle>vehicles;

    while(menu!='8')
    {
    cout << "Welcome to the vehicle management menu." << endl;
    cout << "Please select an option from the following list:" << endl;
    cout << "1: Display vehicles" << endl;
    cout << "2: Add a vehicle" << endl;
    cout << "3: Update a vehicle" << endl;
    cout << "4: Delete a vehicle" << endl;
    cout << "5: Sort inventory by VIN" << endl;
    cout << "6: Search inventory by Make" << endl;
    cout << "7: Read inventory from file (will overwrite any changes)" << endl;
    cout << "8: Write inventory to file and exit" << endl;
    cin >> menu;
        switch(menu)
        {
        // Call to appropriate functions based upon user decision
        case '1': displayInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        case '2': addInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        case '3': updateInventory(vehicles);
            sortInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        case '4': deleteInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        case '5': sortInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        case '6': searchInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        case '7': refreshInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        case '8': sortInventory(vehicles);
            writeInventory(vehicles);
            break;
        //Error/incorrect input checking
        default: cout << endl << "Please make a valid selection" << endl << endl;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Vehicle.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include "Thomas-PA3 Vehicle.h"
#include "Thomas-PA3 Functions.h"
using namespace std;
//Default constructor for Dealer
Dealer::Dealer()
{
    dealerNumber = 0;
}
//Function to get dealer number
int Dealer::getDealerNum()
{
return dealerNumber;
}

void Dealer::setDealerNum(int dealerNumber)
{
    cout << "Please input the new dealer number" << endl;
    cin >> dealerNumber;
}
//Custom constructor for Vehicle
Vehicle::Vehicle(string VIN, string make, string model, int year, double price)
{
    cout << "Vehicle data is initialized" << endl;
}
//Default constructor for Vehicle
Vehicle::Vehicle()
{
    VIN = "0";
    make = "";
    model = "";
    year = 0;
    price = 0;
}
//Functions to return member variables
string Vehicle::getVIN()
{
    return VIN;
}

string Vehicle::getMake()
{
    return make;
}

string Vehicle::getModel()
{
    return model;
}

int Vehicle::getYear()
{
    return year;
}

double Vehicle::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
//Functions to set member variables
void Vehicle::setVIN(string VIN)
{
    cout << "Please input the vehicle's VIN #" << endl;
    cin >> VIN;
}

void Vehicle::setMake(string make)
{
    cout << "Please input the vehicle's make" << endl;
    cin >> VIN;
}

void Vehicle::setModel(string model)
{
    cout << "Please input the vehicle's model" << endl;
    cin >> VIN;
}

void Vehicle::setYear(int year)
{
    cout << "Please input the vehicle's year" << endl;
    cin >> VIN;
}

void Vehicle::setPrice(double price)
{
    cout << "Please input the vehicle's price" << endl;
    cin >> VIN;
}
```

Comment: I've voted to close. You can't just dump all of your code. Please make an effort and create a [mcve] and we'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include "Functions.h" before "Vehicles.h". Therefore, when the compiler sees `vector<Vehicle>`, it doesn't yet know that `Vehicle` will be defined as a class later.

C++ is compiled in three stages. First, the preprocessor runs and executes `#include` statements and the like. This is done once per .cpp file, and the result is fed to the real compiler. The compiler then compiles this result line by line. Finally, the linker glues everything together.

The important stage here is the middle one. Because each .cpp file is compiled in isolation, top to bottom, you put the necessary headers at the top. And if one header needs another, you put one above the other. To make this easy, it can be useful to `#include` one header in the other. After all, all the `#include` statements are executed. Everything ends up in the .cpp file eventually.

One final remark: You generally need to protect yourself against double `#include`s. There's a second preprocessor mechanism for that: surround your .h file with

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

// Real contents of Vehicle.h go here, including any other #include statement

#endif
```

If you now write

```
#include "vehicle.h"
//.. other stuff
#include "vehicle.h"
```

the preprocessor will see the second statement, and note that `VEHICLE_H` was already defined, so the second inclusion is not needed. Spelling note: it's all uppercase to prevent confusion with `class Vehicle` and other similar names, and you can't use a `.` there so the suffix is `_H`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Solved the problem and took my compile errors from over a hundred to less than a dozen! Thank you so much!!!